# SQL DATEADD Returning Incorrect Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

I'm currently writing a query for Visual Studio 2012 and testing it in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio using SQL Server 2008 R2.

At the moment, I've read through MSDN's article on datetimes and DATEADD, but it seems like my syntax is right. I've also read some stuff on Google as well as [How to select last one week data from today's date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266130/how-to-select-last-one-week-data-from-todays-date/13266205#13266205) and [MySQL: DATE_ADD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128736/mysql-date-add) as well as a few more Stack Overflow articles.

The query I'm running at the moment is really simple, just:

```
SELECT [DateTime] AS 'Time'
      ,[RawStatus] AS 'Data'
  FROM [ADatabase].[dbo].[SomeTable]
  WHERE CustomPollerAssignmentID = '6570267A-22E1-4556-B344-EB27D9831419' --Latency Poller
    AND RowID = 000042 --Some Modem Number
    AND DATEADD(HOUR, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= DateTime 
  ORDER BY DateTime DESC
```

What I was expecting this to do was to return the data (network latency in this case) for the last hour. Instead, it's returning the last three hours and thirty minutes. When running the code with the DATEADD statement commented out, it runs just fine and returns everything for the past day or two, the maximum time this table stores latency data.

Now, the strange code above is modeled after what's below, which I know works:

```
SELECT  NMSDS.[SnapshotTimestamp] AS 'Time'
      ,[LatencyValue] AS 'Latency'
  FROM [ADifferentDatabase].[dbo].[AnotherTable] Late
  INNER JOIN ADifferentDatabase.dbo.YetAnotherTable NMSDS ON NMS_Id = 1 
    AND NMSDS.SnapshotID = Late.SnapshotID
  WHERE DATEADD(HOUR, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= NMSDS.SnapshotTimestamp 
    AND InrouteGroupId = @IRID 
    AND NetworkId = @NTID
  ORDER BY [Late].SnapshotID ASC
```

My questions are:

1. What am I missing?
2. Have I formatted my query wrong? And the second is why would it return 3.5 hours instead of one given the fact that the second query actually works and returns things properly?

Comment: Not like it would make a difference, but I would probably do `NMSDS.SnapshotTimestamp >= DATEADD(HOUR, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` as it may use an index.

Comment: Yeah, I tried switching the order in the query before I posted anything, but it didn't change the strange behavior. Also, as I mentioned below (and in the post), the first set of code is the one producing weird behavior. The second one is an example of code that actually works using nearly identical syntax.

Comment: Try applying that filter on the `NMSDS` result set first.

Comment: Well, again, it's the first query that's causing problems (which doesn't have an NMSDS in it), but applying the DATEADD first didn't change anything, it's still returning roughly 3 1/2 hours even though it should be filtering for one.

Comment: Add the dateadd(hour, -1, current_timestamp) to the select clause so you can verify what is being compared to [Datetime]

Comment: I agree with @straycatDBA. There's nothing wrong with your query, which means there's garbage somewhere. Could be regional settings (current_timestamp isn't returning the same time zone as you expect). So add current_timestamp to your select clause and I believe the solution will become apparent.

Comment: Hmmm, good catch. There's definitely an offset of about 1:07h which would put it in the middle of the ocean in terms of time zones. I wasn't even noticing that. That's really weird. So, if I understand correctly, what's happening is: The data's being stored at an X offset from the current time, but the server's time is correct, so it's grabbing from server time until max time (which is technically an hour or so from right now)?

Comment: Another problem is that these pollers keep turning themselves off (a separate issue that I'm not in charge of fixing), so the actual offset isn't 1:07h, it's something bigger since, yesterday, I was getting about three and a half hours' worth of data and, since I last posted, it's catching up because the poller's shut itself off again. -_-;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to say that you are missing timezone data.
From your queries, there is no data what timezone the servers are in, or what timezone they are inserting data to.

Comment: That actually was part of the issue. As it turns out, the NMS stores data in UTC while the server is in East Coast time. Once I converted it, I found out that the weird offsets were just caused by the poller just intermittently shutting off.

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want?? Do you want the data for the last clock hour? (i.e., if it's 10:37 you want all data between 9:00 and 10:00)

or do you want the data for the past one hour? (i.e., if it's 10:37:12 you want all data between 9:37:13 and 10:37:12)

For the first, change the where clause to

```
...And NMSDS.SnapshotTimestamp >= 
            DateAdd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Current_Timestamp)-1, 0), 
   And NMSDS.SnapshotTimestamp <  
            DateAdd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Current_Timestamp), 0)
```

For the second, it's easier...

```
 ... And NMSDS.SnapshotTimestamp > Current_Timestamp - 1/24
```

but I admit I'm really confused by the value 6 in the second query... Why a 6, if you are trying for the data for the last ***single*** hour ??

Comment: @CharlesBertana I think Cthulhu was pointing out that the second query returns the correct data, while the first query does not and wonders why, since the queries appear similar in format, it does.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The second code sample is the one that actually works whereas the first bit of code is producing the strange behavior.

Comment: @CharleBertana Your solution does work with the double DATEADDs, but shouldn't I be able to do it with a single one like in the working second query?